# QuartoDocument input

Tags: r, input, shiny, readline

I'm not sure how to word it because I haven't been able to find stuff on it, but I want to make a data.frame() that will use an initial input value that you can put into a prompt box on my website, whether it's with readline() or another function I don't know about.

I've tried readline() as well as library(shiny)'s titlePanel().

I want to know if there's anything else I can do before using html.

Comment: Hi! I don't quite get your question. How is this related to Quarto, as the title says? I guess you are working on a Shiny app. Have you used `textInput()` yet?